# Add field to a jquery element and use with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a field to a jQuery element and use it inside the click event callback, why doesn't it work, is it possible?

```
$button = $("#myButton");
$button.i = 5;
$button.on('click',function(){
    console.log($(this).i)
});
```

Comment: by field if you mean an attribute? if so you need to do this `$button.attr('i', 5)`

Comment: or, if you need to store some data on the button then use the `.data()` on the button. check out its documentation https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply not accessing the same object in each case.

Inside the jQuery event handler callback, `this` is equal to the DOM node itself (i.e. the  element, not the jQuery object that you have set the `i` property on.

There are a number of ways around this:

1. You could reference $button in your callback function
2. You set an attribute on the DOM node using jQuery's .attr()

   - E.g. $button.attr('i', 5)

Hope that helps!

---

UPDATE in response to your question:

In the scenario there is only one DOM node, the `<button>` - we can think of it as one underlying object to the whole thing.

When you create your $button variable, you do that by giving your DOM node over to jQuery and it gives you back a **new** object. This is what contains all those great jQuery methods, such as `.on()` which you are using above.

I.e. $button and `<button>` are different objects.

Now let's think about your `i` property...

You are setting `i` as a property of the JavaScript object $button, but as we determined above, this is a distinctly separate object (created for us by jQuery) from the `<button>` DOM node. Setting `i` on $button has no bearing on the DOM node.

Now, in your jQuery provided click handler, the library sets the `this` binding to your original DOM node, *not* your $button object.

Inside the click handler you do something very similar to the beginning of the script - you have a reference to the DOM node `<button>` (`this`) and you give it to jQuery so that it can **once again create a new object**.

So `<button>` it not the same object as $button, which is also not the same object as $(this) in your click handler.

Finally, let's consider the jQuery `.attr()` helper function.

If instead of setting an `i` property on $button, you use the .attr method to set an `i` *attribute*, internally jQuery will update the DOM node itself by assigning an attribute `i`, containing the value `5`.

As we determined at the beginning, the DOM node has been the same all along and so we can easily access this attribute again in the click handler!

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. I just wonder why, because when I got "this" inside the function and surround it with $ it created a new jQuery instance from the button element so why the ".attr" remains there?

Comment: Updated my answer to give some more explanation. Please mark the answer as accepted if this indeed helped you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Read little bit about [jquery.data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

```
var button = $("#myButton");
button.data('i', 5);
button.click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('i'))
});
```